# Eclipse: Show job progress on status line in custom perspective/view

Tags: java, eclipse, progress-bar, eclipse-rcp

In my RCP application I have a custom view in custom perspective. I am starting a job which can take some seconds:

```
    final Job job = new Job("My job") {

        @Override
        protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
            monitor.worked(1);
            // ....
            return Status.OK_STATUS;
        }

    };
    job.setUser(true);
    job.schedule();
```

To make it visible to the user that the job is still running I want to make the progress visible in the status line of the perspective.

What do I have to do to make the progress of my job appear in the status line (in the bottom right corner of the perspective)?

Comment: What sort of RCP? e4 or 3.x compatiblity?

Comment: @greg-449 The target environment is Neon (4.6) and newer.

Comment: I mean are you doing an e4 RCP using an Application.e4xmi or a 3.x compatibility mode RCP using org.eclipse.ui.xxx plugins? You can do either in Neon.

Comment: @greg-449 The app exists for some years now. Therefore I am very sure it is using the 3.x compatibility mode.

Comment: Just using `setUser(false)` should just display the job progress in the standard status line progress area.

Comment: @greg-449 Unfortunately not. If I do so nothing is visible at all. Do I have to initialize the status line in a special way?

Comment: Your RCP may be leaving out the code that does the status line. What an RCP includes varies enormously. I think the code is in the `org.eclipse.ui.workbench` plugin. I don't know what setup is required.